# Databinding not working with constraint layout Groups

Tags: android, data-binding, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

I have used group views in my layout `fragment_hurdle_otp.xml` file.

```
.
.
.

<android.support.constraint.Group
            android:id="@+id/group_navigate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_navigate_option,tv_navigate_option" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_navigate_option"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/space_16"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/space_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_space_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_navigate_option"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_navigate_option"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_lock_vector" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_navigate_option"
            style="@style/LoginButtonLight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wh_40"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_space"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin_8"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_space_small"
            android:text="@{vm.tvNavigateOption}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_verify"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_navigate_option"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selectable_item_background"
            android:onClick="@{()->vm.onNavigate()}"
            tools:text="@string/login_with_password" />
.
.
.
```

But while building , generating the Binding files for this layout fails and throws a compilation error.

> Class elements: (java.lang.String,java.lang.String)void init
>   /Users/.../../..application/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/developersProductionDebug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDevelopersProductionDebug/out/com/phone/app/databinding/FragmentHurdleOtpBinding.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>     public final Group groupNavigate;

Everything works fine if I remove the group views.

Comment: A simple clean +  build should fix this. If not please post the code error is pointing to.

Comment: Are you still using `support` library or migrated to `AndroidX`?

Comment: Migrated to androidX

Comment: The support library has been superseded by AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX.more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Then use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` instead of `android.support.constraint.Group`

Comment: That worked, thanks @Md.Asaduzzaman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already migrated your project to `AndroidX`. So, You have to use `AndroidX` library instead of `Support`. In your project don't mix `Support` library with `AndroidX`.

Use

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
```

instead of

```
android.support.constraint.Group
```

Also include `AndroidX` library of `ConstraintLayout` in your module level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```